# RTL - Does android:autoMirrored work with png images?

Tags: android, internationalization

I read that since 4.4, android supports autoMirroring:

> On previous versions of Android, if your app includes images that should reverse their horizontal orientation for right-to-left layouts, you must include the mirrored image in a drawables-ldrtl/ resource directory. Now, the system can automatically mirror images for you by enabling the autoMirrored attribute on a drawable resource or by calling setAutoMirrored(). When enabled, the Drawable is automatically mirrored when the layout direction is right-to-left.

Link:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Does this only work for vector graphics, or can it also be used with bitmaps like png files?

Attribute android:autoMirrored:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

My Question is, if I embedded left-arrow.png as a resource in my app, could I somehow define this autoMirrior property for my image so that when the users device is set to an rtl language android will invert it dynamically. Is this possible? If so, how do I configure the property of a png image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can wrap your drawable in a `bitmap` resource

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/left-arrow"
    android:autoMirrored="true">
</bitmap>
```

Comment: I think I understand, I had been including bitmaps previously just by the filename. Reading now about XML Bitmap, which is what I believe you are refering to here. So within an XML defined bitmap I can set the autoMirrored property? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html